# How to create patch file,how to send patch file to client machine

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, distribution

after install the software in the client machine i wan to send the next updates to client machine,how i send like a patch file and install automatically in the client place,can one give some idea about this...

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce is designed to ease the deployment of windows forms app. Check it out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

From that link:

> ClickOnce is a deployment technology that enables you to create
>   self-updating Windows-based applications that can be installed and run
>   with minimal user interaction. ClickOnce deployment overcomes three
>   major issues in deployment:
>
> Difficulties in updating applications.
>
> With Microsoft Windows Installer deployment, whenever an application is updated, the user
>   must reinstall the whole application; with ClickOnce deployment, you
>   can provide updates automatically. Only those parts of the application
>   that have changed are downloaded, and then the full, updated
>   application is reinstalled from a new side-by-side folder.
>
> Impact to the user's computer.
>
> With Windows Installer deployment, applications often rely on shared components, with the potential for
>   versioning conflicts; with ClickOnce deployment, each application is
>   self-contained and cannot interfere with other applications.
>
> Security permissions.
>
> Windows Installer deployment requires administrative permissions and allows only limited user installation;
>   ClickOnce deployment enables non-administrative users to install and
>   grants only those Code Access Security permissions necessary for the
>   application.

Comment: I can't tell you in any more detail than the docs can. You need to familiarise yourself with them.